Pin a portable applikation to taskbar using PowerShell (Win 10/11 and Server 2022)
First, I do not have an AUMID
Primary OS is Windows Server 2022
I want to pin an application to the taskbar, and to start. The portable application is copied to the target with a PS script, and i have it in the Start menu.
It is a link to this "app.exe" i want to pin to the taskbar.

I can tell you that one way is in the following PowerShell environment path. . .
"$ENV:AppData\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"
Another way is through the registry. . .
"HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband"
. . .with names like "Favorites", "FavoritesChanges", "Pinned", and "LayoutCycle"
You would have to share your PowerShell code you have so far before we can offer any help, but those are some places you could look at.

Trying both, i have read out from reg-database and added shortcuts to the AppData folder, cleared icon cach before restart without luck. The shortcuts are present, but not visibel in the taskbar

If you post the code you currently have I am more than happy to try and assist you.
